# How to create a list with attributes with Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

Is it possible to create a list with attributes with Rcpp? And if so, how?

I need such a list for the `shinyTree` package, which requires this structure and my R code is quite slow, as I need several nested loops to go through all the list-levels.

This is the structure I need:

```
list(Name1 = structure("", type = "root", sticon = "fa-icon", stclass = "color"))
```

> ```
> $Name1
> [1] ""
> attr(,"type")
> [1] "root"
> attr(,"sticon")
> [1] "fa-icon"
> attr(,"stclass")
> [1] "color"
> ```

Comment: There are several examples for setting attributes at the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) for more examples, but here is a quick one:

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List quickdemo() {
  Rcpp::CharacterVector v = Rcpp::CharacterVector::create("");
  v.attr("type") = "root";
  v.attr("sticon") = "fa-icon";
  v.attr("stclass") = "color";
  return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("Name1") = v);
}

/*** R
quickdemo()
*/
```

#### Output

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/54693381/answer.cpp")

R> quickdemo()
$Name1
[1] ""
attr(,"type")
[1] "root"
attr(,"sticon")
[1] "fa-icon"
attr(,"stclass")
[1] "color"

R>
```

Comment: beautiful, thank you. I actually looked through the gallery, but there are so many articles that I seemingly overlooked the relevant ones. Nevertheless, many thanks for the answer and the amount of useful resources!

Comment: ;-)  -- that's why there is a _custom_ Google Search function right there!

Answer (score 3):

First, create the list with `Rcpp::List::create()`.
Add the single named entry with `Rcpp::Named("NameHere") = data`.
Then add the additional markup with `my_list.attr("attribute-name") = attribute_val`.

This is given by:

```
#include<Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List create_list_with_attr(Rcpp::CharacterVector x) {
    Rcpp::List val = Rcpp::List::create(
        Rcpp::Named("Name1") = x
    );

    val.attr("type") = "root";
    val.attr("sticon") = "fa-icon";
    val.attr("stclass") = "color";

    return val;
}
```

From there, we can test it with:

```
create_list_with_attr(" ")
# $Name1
# [1] " "
#
# attr(,"type")
# [1] "root"
# attr(,"sticon")
# [1] "fa-icon"
# attr(,"stclass")
# [1] "color"
```

Comment: Almost, but not quite.  In his example the inner is just a char.

Comment: But have an upvote as you beat me to it when I got interrupted due to something else :)